# Stationarity of categorical time series

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, stationarity

I'm familiar with real-valued time series' stationarity, but what does it mean for $X_{t}$, a categorical-valued time series, to be stationary?
Edit: an example of $X_{t}$ is the reduction of daily rainfall volumes to
a binary series of 'd' and 'w' for dry and wet.

Comment: Stationarity conditions do not exclude categorical variables, now do they? So the definition is the same.

Comment: @RichardHardy , how is the mean of a categorical-valued time series calculated?

Comment: Mmm, I don't know. Does that mean we cannot define weak stationarity for categorical variables? Probably. Meanwhile, strong stationarity does not consider moments, so there should be no problem with it.

Comment: The usual definitions of time series do not allow for values to be in "categories": they must be numerical.  Please, then, explain what you mean by a "categorical-valued time series."